# Find Minimal Polynomial of $T_p = P^{-1}AP$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I got this problem: The transformation $T_p:M_{2\times 2}^{\mathbb{C}} \to M_{2\times 2}^{\mathbb{C}}$ is defined by: $T_p(X)=P^{-1}XP$, for any $X \in M_{2\times 2}^{\mathbb{C}}$.

$P=\begin{pmatrix}
i & 2\\ 
-1 & -i
\end{pmatrix}$

Find the minimal polynomial of $T_p$

So the minimal polynomial of $P$ is $\lambda^2+3$, but I don't really understand how to apply it to $T_p$. $P$ is the change of basis matrix for $X$, and the minimal polynomial of $T_p$ appears to depend on $X$.

For example:

1. If $X = I$ then $T_p(X) = I$, which makes $m_{T_p} = \lambda-1$.
2. If $X = P$ then $T_p(X) = P$, which makes $m_{T_p} = \lambda^2+3$.

How can I even begin to find the minimal polynomial of $T_p$ without knowing anything about $X$?

Comment: I was thinking in this direction, but it made no sense to me because anything that divides both of these polynomials has a degree >2, which rules it out. The answer provided by H. H. Rugh however implies that I should look for a 4-degree polynomial, but that makes no sense to me at all. Is this the case? If so, why?

Comment: Indeed, the minimum polynomial is at most of degree $4$ as you're working on a $\mathbb C$-linear space of dimension $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interpretation when viewing the map $T_p$ as a map from the 4 dimensional vector space of 2 by 2 matrices to itself. In that way $T_p$ corresponds to a 4 by 4 matrix which may be calculated. The characteristic polynomial of that is then of degree 4. Representing a 2 by 2 matrix 
$$ X=\left( \begin{matrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \end{matrix} \right)$$
as a vector 
$$ \vec{X}= \left( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{matrix} \right)$$

One finds that $\vec{T_p({X})}=M\vec{X}$ with a matrix (after a lengthy calculation):

$$ M=\frac13 \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & i & -2i & 2\\ -2i & -1 & -4 & 2i\\ 
  i & -1 & -1 & -i \\ 2 & -i & 2i & 1 \end{matrix} \right) $$

The characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^4 -2\lambda^2+1$ and the minimal is $\lambda^2 -1$. This (miraculously) is also explained by $P^2=-3I$ which  yields $T_p(T_p(X)) = X$. To see this note that

$$ T_p(T_p(X)) = P^{-1}( P^{-1} X P) P = (-\frac13 I) X  (-3I) = X$$

In 4D space this corresponds to precisely a (minimal) polynomial of $\lambda^2-1$. In retrospect one could have tried to see that form the start, which might have been the intention of the problem setter...